# 'numpy.int64' object is not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

No entiendo el problema con éste código:

```
h = 1
x = np.arange(-8, 32, h) 
y = np.arange(32, 73, h) 


for i,x in enumerate(x):
    print(x)
    for j,y in enumerate(y):
        print(y)
```

los últimos tres elementos que imprime son:

71

72

-7

Luego salta el error ya mencionado. El programa se rompe cuando tiene que usar por segunda vez el segundo for loop, pero no veo los motivos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al parecer el problema viene por los nombres de las variables:

Al principio al enumerar `y` es un `array` en la primera iteración, pero en la segunda iteración `y` mantiene su valor de contexto y se queda con su último valor que seria `72`

Puede verificarlo imprimiendo `y` antes de la iteración:

```
for i,x in enumerate(x):
    print(x)
    print(y)
    for j,y in enumerate(y):
        print(y)
```

**Solución:** Para corregir esto solo usa nombres de variables diferentes, como el siguiente ejemplo:

```
import numpy as np

h = 1
xx = np.arange(-8, 32, h) 
yy = np.arange(32, 73, h) 


for i,x in enumerate(xx):
    print(x)
    for j,y in enumerate(yy):
        print(y)
```